# How to set GPIO output drive level from the cmd line

Tags: gpio

You can set the GPIO output drive level from 2 to 16 mA. Several libraries have facilities for this but how do I do it directly from the terminal?

Comment: For posterity: Beware this **does not** set the actual current (or control the maximum).  It sets the safe maximum that can be driven.  It will not prevent more than that being sunk or sourced, which may cause permanent damage.

Answer (score 1):

The only libraries which provide for setting the pad drive level that I am aware of are [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) and (my) [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html).

I don't know if wiringPi's [gpio](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/) utility has the ability.

The pigpio [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) utility provides the [pads](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#PADS) command.